# "The IIS Express settings are missing the App Url property" when trying to configure ASP.NET 5 project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, iis-express

I downloaded a sample ASP.NET 5 (vNext) application and tried to configure it to run on my local machine.

When I opened the Project Properties window and switched to the Debug tab, the App URL field is empty and cannot be edited:

[image: Empty App URL field]

When I try to change from IIS Express to the `web` profile, or even close the Properties window, I get this error:

[image: IIS Express error]

> The IIS Express settings are missing the App URL property. This is required to configure IIS express to run the site.

At this point, Visual Studio is totally stuck, and won't even quit. I had to kill the process via the Task Manager to get out.

How can this property be set if the field is locked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The project was missing the `iisSettings` section in `Properties\launchSettings.json`.

The **original** `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      },
      "sdkVersion": "dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final"
    }
  }
}
```

I had to add this section above `profiles`:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49901/",
      "sslPort": 0
  }
}
```

After adding this, I was able to modify the settings normally via the Properties window.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why you can't make required changes of the App URL in Visual Studio, but I would suggest you to change the setting using some text editor.

Look at the subdirectory `Properties` of your project directory and examine the file `launchSettings.json`. You will find `iisSettings.iisExpress.applicationUrl` with the App URL. You need just to edit or to include the property in the file `launchSettings.json`. See [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html?highlight=applicationurl#development) for details.

Answer (score 0):

For the same error in my case  "IIS Express" section was somehow corrupted. I've restored launchSettings.json from Source Control

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue but manually updating the launchsettings.json file with the application url did not work, but adding it via the Project > Properties > Debug > General > Open Debug Launch Profiles UI did the trick for some reason.